# CSS child clearing parent float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a two-column layout, sidebar on the left, content on the right.

So I float the sidebar left, and give the content on the right a margin. All is fine and well...

Until, a child element of the content has a clear applied to it, it jumps below the sidebar.

Is there a way to make children element only float and clear within it's parent container?

As a picture is worth 1000 words, here's a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qRYYm/1/

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski - did you mean to press 'Update' in the jsfiddle first?

Comment: I assume that there's no specific reason why a child element would have a clear applied to it, the question is just how to solve the problem that is created when a clear ever is applied. Is that right?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you add `overflow:auto;` to `.content` that should see you right.

Comment: Perfect. Could you provide a bit more explanation as to why this works?

Comment: The problem is that containing DIV will not stretch to the height of the tallest elements when it contains floated elements. Adding overflow:auto (or hidden or scroll) will cause it to expand. More info here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: Just curious, what is the default value of `overflow` for a DIV?

Comment: @Justin - The default value is 'visible' iirc.

Comment: @BillyMoat - I believe the reason is that certain styles, including `overflow:auto`, create a new "block formatting context" which means that floats outside it are not considered for clearing purposes. See the [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) and [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) pages on MDN for more info.

Comment: Since it seems like the entire purpose is to create a new block formatting context, would `display: flow-root;` be a more straightforward solution?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
aside{
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qRYYm/2/

Comment: That's the effect I'm after - but is it possible without using absolute positioning?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using clear. You can use overflow:hidden with main container

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">Two</div>    
</div>

.content { float: left; overflow: hidden; width: 900px; }
aside { float: left; width: 100px; }
```

Also, you should not use the margin-left:100px to push the content away from the left hand column. Float both left. I find that the columns like to be in a main wrapper. It's cozier that way.

Comment: floating both left doesn't allow the second column to take up the remaining width... ie; be flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way also.

```
.left{float:left;}
.right {float:right;}
.clear{clear:both;}

<div>
    <div class="left">SideBar</div>
    <div class="right">
             <div>
                 <div class="left">content 1</div>
                 <div class="left">content 2</div>
                 <div class="clear"></div>
             </div>
   </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

When applying float on any div(s) ,put them in a parent div and clear within same parent div